# Loop through array of objects, and combine arrays within objects

Tags: javascript

How can I loop through the data array of objects, and then join each guestList array into a single array to be used elsewhere?

```
   const data = 
      [
        {
            "guestList": [
                {
                    "firstName": "test",
                    "surname": "test",
                    "email": "test@test.com",
                },
                {
                    "firstName": "test",
                    "surname": "tesT",
                    "email": "test@test.com",
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "guestList": [
                {
                    "firstName": "test",
                    "surname": "test",
                    "email": "test@test.com",
                },
                {
                    "firstName": "test",
                    "surname": "tesT",
                    "email": "test@test.com",
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "guestList": [
                {
                    "firstName": "test",
                    "surname": "test",
                    "email": "test@test.com",
                },
                {
                    "firstName": "test",
                    "surname": "tesT",
                    "email": "test@test.com",
                }
            ],
        }
      ]
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` and destructuring like this:

```js
 const data =[{"guestList": [{"firstName": "test","surname": "test","email": "test@test.com",},{"firstName": "test","surname": "tesT","email": "test@test.com",}],},{"guestList": [{"firstName": "test","surname": "test","email": "test@test.com",},{"firstName": "test","surname": "tesT","email": "test@test.com",}],},{"guestList": [{"firstName": "test","surname": "test","email": "test@test.com",},{"firstName": "test","surname": "tesT","email": "test@test.com",}],}];
 
const result = data.flatMap(({guestList}) => guestList);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I can accept your answer in 11 minutes, thank you!!!